# Golang emoji render

Tags: golang, telegram, графика, emoji

С помощью freetype произвожу рендеринг текста на png.
Никак не получается отрендерить ***цветные*** emoji.

Желательно, чтобы поддерживались все emoji из телеграмма.

Впринципе, мне будет достаточно найти решение, которое по unicode emoji создает отдельную цветную картинку. Тогда я смогу вручную ее уменьшить и вставить в текст.

Подскажите, какие есть варианты?